# Add table row on dropdown select & delete row. Only once add the row from particular dropdown select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My requirement is as follows:

I have table with default row with dropdown in 1st column, Once i select an option from dropdown, 1 table row should be added, with same content as main row & should add delete button for that added row. Delete button should not visible for 1st row once 1 row is added then only delete button visible for 1st row. Pls help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

My code as follows

```html
<table id="potable" class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="5%">Sr.no</th>
            <th width="20%">Items</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <select id="additems" name="additems" class="form-control" required="required">                                                
                    <option selected>-- Select --</option>
                    <option><a href="" id="addnewpo">Add new</a></option>
                    <option value="1"> Abc </option>
                    <option value="2"> IT services </option>
                    <option value="3"> JS Enterprises</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Dell 500 series</td>
            <td>55,333</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>NA</td>
            <td>5,53,330</td>
            <td>8%</td>
            <td width="2%"><a class="actions-btn" id="delete-row" title="Delete"><span class="icon ico-delete ico-2x"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use javascript. What have you done using javascript?

Comment: I have done to add row on button click by jquery but not on dropdwon select. I want it on dropdown select.

Comment: Please dont put requirements only on op since you dont pay so people. Please put effort on op add what you tried ang where you are stuck

Comment: I stuck in add row on dropdwon select

Comment: I don't understand what are you exactly want!!! You want to add a row to the table, each time the user choose a value in the drop down??

Comment: Having issue, dropdown on tax coulmn not display jsfiddle.net/s75ph25d

Comment: I ahve change the code as per change request, pls check this jsfiddle.net//3zc26tex 
Here sr.no should be 1,2,3 ... & cuurently it add row only once when i click addmore, it should add row every time i clcik on addmore button. Pls check & update asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/60fxtfen/1/

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="additems"]', function(){
 if($('#additems option:selected').text() === "Add new"){
   $('table tbody').append($('table tbody tr:first-child').clone());
    $('table tbody tr:last-child td:first-child').text($('table tbody tr').length);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="potable" class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="5%">Sr.no</th>
            <th width="20%">Items</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Tax</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <select id="additems" name="additems" class="form-control" required="required">                                                
                    <option selected>-- Select --</option>
                    <option>Add new</option>
                    <option value="1"> Abc </option>
                    <option value="2"> IT services </option>
                    <option value="3"> JS Enterprises</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Dell 500 series</td>
            <td>55,333</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>NA</td>
            <td>5,53,330</td>
            <td>8%</td>
            <td width="2%"><a class="actions-btn" id="delete-row" title="Delete"><span class="icon ico-delete ico-2x"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have created the baseline, you need to let me know where to add delete & edit option.

Comment: Thanks,
only dropdwon should be there in new row rest columns should be blank

Comment: @JonPan ... Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/60fxtfen/2/

Comment: @JonPan ... I have already shared the updated fiddle, have a look and let me know, if the requirement is same or not...

Comment: Almost same but delete button on each row & it should delete that perticular row only. Also add row only from dropdown in that perticular row.
Also delete button at 1st row shold clear thetahe perticular row.
 See this image  ibb.co/bNRiX5

Comment: @JonPan Here you go with the solution with delete option for each row https://jsfiddle.net/60fxtfen/3/

Comment: @JonPan ... If you want to discuss anything, we can definitely discuss over chat. There is a chat option in Stackoverflow..

Comment: Having issue, dropdown on tax coulmn not display 

https://jsfiddle.net/s75ph25d/

Comment: one more help pls https://jsfiddle.net/uLwyvsg4/ New row add only select from that perticular dropdwon let say if i select dropdown from 1st row then adds row, when i select dropdwon from 2nd row then add row. add new row textboxes should be blank. Now it add rows from any rows dropdown. And add row should be select the option other than AddNew And when i click 1st row delete it clears the textboxex only now it delete the row.

Comment: @JonPan ... Please update the question... Because I believe I have give the answer as per the question you asked.. This is a forum to help each other but there are certain rules attach to it, rather we help other people who have similar queries / question based on your question. So it very important what you are asking as a question, so insist you to update the question.

Comment: Updated as requested. Pls check what do wrong in jsfiddle.net/uLwyvsg4 

 i want to achive
New row add only select from that perticular dropdwon let say if i select dropdown from 1st row then adds row, when i select dropdwon from 2nd row then add row. add new row textboxes should be blank. Now it add rows from any rows dropdown. And add row should be select the option other than AddNew And when i click 1st row delete it clears the textboxex only now it delete the row

Comment: Thanks,
Will check & let you know

Comment: its working, but each dropdwon (in items column) on each row add row only once, means if select option from dropdown it add the row, but if change the option it should not add the row.
I can change the option but it should add row only once in particular row

Comment: I have done with drop down clear, only 1 thing is remaining i.e each row dropdown select add rows only once, if i change the option then it won't add row again. Currently it adds the row when i change the dropdown options

http://jsfiddle.net/qe9btz31/

Comment: Works perfect, Thanks.

Comment: I ahve change the code as per change request pls check this https://jsfiddle.net//3zc26tex/

Here sr.no should be 1,2,3 ... & cuurently it add row only once when i click addmore, it should add row every time i clcik on addmore button.
Pls check & update asap

Comment: pls look above comment

Comment: @JonPan... I'm bit surprise that you are not asking for the explanation of the solution. I'm sorry to say that you may be in the similar problem in future if you don't understand where you are stuck with the problem & the solution. I'm really sorry to be harsh.

Comment: Actually i am not asking the explanation, might be my way of asking is wrong, i just chage the code as per change request, & i stuck in adding rows & sr.no increasing  stuff.
I apologies for this.

Comment: Here you go with solution https://jsfiddle.net/3zc26tex/3/ .. Two features are updated one is Serial number & delete functionality for newly added row's.

Comment: Hey, buddy it working perfect but 1 issue, when i delete row it wont decrease the sr.no

Comment: Working Perfect buddy, you are the hero. Pls share your skypeid

Comment: Sure, 
well-noted

Comment: I need 1 small help on this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/3zc26tex/4/

I dont want delete option for first row.

Comment: @VishaalM . Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/3zc26tex/5/

Comment: Its Working, Thanks